# Sign jar file by java code

Tags: java, applet, jarsigner

I have a question. When I sign my JAR file, which I will open as an applet, I use Command Prompt and command:

```
jarsigner -keystore <path to key store> <path to jar file> <alias>
```

But is it possible to do this by using only Java? I would start my JAR with some `Jarsigner.class` file by Command Prompt, then it would be automatically signed and then I could open this JAR in my browser as an applet. The keystore would be placed as a resource in JAR.

Comment: If you are just looking for a shortcut to signing jars you could probably create a batch file that does it for you.

Comment: @ck1221 No, the singing must be done from jar itself, because I don't have access to creating some bat files.

Comment: Why? Your IDE will do it, ANT will do it, Maven will do it? You won't be deploying new applets at runtime surely?

Comment: I just wanna know if it would be possible.